# Help finding an anime whose protagonist's biggest dream was that he was never born

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm trying to find an anime I watched in 2005/2006. It was a short one (probably around 12-13 episodes) and I remember only one character - a dark haired guy (his name started with Y, but I'm not sure) whose biggest dream was to have never been born. The point was that he didn't want to commit suicide, but simply never have existed in the first place.

All I remember from the storyline is that there was another guy who fought to make the dark haired guy's dream come true. In the end, he succeeds and the other one disappears/vanishes - as if he was never been born. It wasn't a yaoi or shounen-ai, but it did have a certain atmosphere of a shounen-ai.

Truth be told it was a really sad story, but I can't stop thinking about it and as it wasn't popular I can't find its title. Unfortunately, that's all I remember.

Does anyone of you maybe recognise this anime? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that was Nabari no Ou, and Yoite is the character you remember.  Both the anime and manga have been translated to English and released in both their entirety.

The manga, if you are curious, continues beyond Yoite's erasure (is that the right word?).

Comment: Try to add pic, synopsis and if possible episode where the description of OP match.